Character of Galois group factors through a specific number field
Let $k$ be a number field and $\chi: C_k \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ a quadratic idele class character. We know that this corresponds to a character $\rho: \mathrm{Gal}(k^{\mathrm{ab}}/k) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Now, the kernel $\mathrm{ker}(\chi)$ of $\chi$ corresponds (via class field theory) to a finite quadratic extension $K/k$. My question is why does $\rho$ factor through $\mathrm{Gal}(k^{\mathrm{ab}}/k) \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$?
Generally speaking I know that it has to factor through $\textit{some}$ finite extension $L$ of $k$, but why does it have to be $K$?
Thanks!

Well, if $\operatorname{Gal}(k^{\operatorname{ab}}/K)$ is the kernel of the surjective quadratic character $\operatorname{Gal}(k^{\operatorname{ab}}/k) \rightarrow {1,-1}$, where $K$ is some finite abelian extension of $k$, then this means that the quotient group
$$\operatorname{Gal}(k^{\operatorname{ab}}/k)/\operatorname{Gal}(k^{\operatorname{ab}}/K) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$$
has only two elements.  That means that $K$ has to be a quadratic extension of $k$.
